# Connecting Oracle in JDBC request in SoapUI

Tags: oracle, jdbc, request, driver, soapui

can you please help me with the following issue:

I want to connect to an Oracle database through  a SoapUI JDBC Request, but I keep getting this error:

```
"Can't get the Connection for the specified properties; java.sql.SQLException : arguments non valides dans l'appel"
```

I used the following:

```
Driver : oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Connection String : jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:sid
```

Printscreen :

[image]

Is there a problem with my Connection string?
Also, I wonder where should I put my username/password.

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried the documentation? http://www.soapui.org/jdbc/testing-jdbc-databases.html

Comment: Yes but I have SOAPUI, which is not the same version... Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The problem is surely that you're not specifying user/password for the DB. You can specify the user and password in the connection URL as follows:

`jdbc:oracle:thin:USER/PASSWORD@HOST:PORT:SID`

The other thing necessary in *SOAPUI* to work with *jdbc* is to add the drivers in `SOAPUI_HOME\bin\ext` but for your screenshoots seems that this is already do it.

The problem is that you add two version of it: `ojdbc14.jar` and `ojdbc6.jar`.

To avoid class loader problems you must remove one of these. Since probably you're running SOAPUI with JRE 1.7 or higher I recommend to remove the `ojdbc14.jar` and keeps the `ojdbc6.jar` version; because the first one is for JDK 1.4 and the second one is for JDK 1.6.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 1):

This one will work:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:USER/PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/SID
```